# Copying files while SSHed onto a computer

Tags: networking, ssh, file-transfer, webserver, cp

I am trying to upload some website files to a computer I am SSHed into and I'm not sure the correct command to use. I've tried looking up the `cp` command instructions but I can't work out what to put in the space for the remote machine, since I am of the understanding that my local IP address will be masked from the outside.

So, how would I go about finding out what my local IP address is for the purposes of copying files from my computer to a remote server via the command-line accessed on the remote server? (I am assuming at this stage that the `cp` Linux command would be the best way to do so?)

Currently the only other way I have to upload files is via a C-Panel interface which is quite cumbersome and only allows the copying of one file at a time, which, as the website grows, is likely to become more of a significant problem.

Any help would be very, very much appreciated.

Comment: this link may be helpful - was answered in a previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710946/copying-files-across-computers-using-ssh-and-mac-os-x-terminal

Comment: Thanks Mike, the link it useful, but I'm still not clear on how to find out my local IP and use it within the cp command. The link you posted to seems to contain info on how to use scp, but not how to find out your IP and/or hostname as recognised by a remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [scp](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/7/man/scp.html) command, which allows one to copy files from one system to another using the SSH protocol, rather than the cp command. If your local computer is a Linux or OS X system, then you likely already have scp on the system. If your local computer is a Microsoft Windows system and you are using PuTTY, it also has a command line utility, pscp. Or you could use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net), which provides a graphical user interface (GUI).

To copy multiple files at once, you can use an scp command similar to the following one, assuming you wished to copy all html files in the current directory on your local system to a server example.com and store them beneath a directory named public_html on the remote system. The directory path on the remote system will be relative to your home directory on that system. You can also specify your home directory with `~`, e.g. `~/public_html/`. The period at the end indicates you want to give the files the same name on the remote system as they have on the local system.

```
scp *.html your_remote_username@example.com:public_html/.
```

See [scp or sftp copy mulitple files with single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886179/scp-or-sftp-copy-mulitple-files-with-single-command) for other examples of copying mulitple files.

You should run the command outside of your current SSH session. The `ssh` command is for interactive logins whereas the `scp`, or alternatively, [sftp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol), command is run separately for file transfers.

You don't need to know your local IP address for the command. But, if you want to know your local IP address, you can obtain it by visiting [WhatIsMyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com) with a browser on your local system. You would only need to know your local IP address to use the scp command if you were copying files in the opposite direction from the remote system to your local system. In that case the local system would also need to be functioning as an SSH server and have appropriate firewall rules configured.